# async parallel request - partial render

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express

What is the proper way to partially render a view following an async parallel request?

Currently I am doing the following

```
// an example using an object instead of an array
async.parallel({
    one: function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 1);
            // can I partially merge the results and render here?
        }, 200);
    },
    two: function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 2);
            // can I partially merge the results and render here?
        }, 100);
    }
},
function(err, results) {
    // results is now equals to: {one: 1, two: 2}
    // merge the results and render a view
    res.render('mypage.ejs', { title: 'Results'});

});
```

It is basically working fine, but, if I have a `function1, function2, ..., functionN` the view  will be rendered only when the slowest function will have completed.

I would like to find the proper way to be able to render the view as soon as the first function is returning to minimise the user delay, and add the results of the function as soon as they are available.

Comment: How would you expect it to work if the functions complete in random order? I doubt you could send partial data (in random order) like that. Have you considered doing multiple partial requests from the client instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you want is facebook's bigpipe: https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=389414033919. fortunately, this is easy with nodejs because streaming is built in. unfortunately, template systems are bad at this because async templates are a pain in the butt. however, this is much better than doing any additional AJAX requests.

basic idea is you first send a layout:

```
res.render('layout.ejs', function (err, html) {
  if (err) return next(err)

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
  res.write(html.replace('</body></html>', ''))

  // Ends the response. 
  // `writePartials` should not return anything in the callback!
  writePartials(res.end.bind(res, '</body></html>'))
})
```

you can't send `</body></html>` because your document isn't finished. then `writePartials` would be a bunch of async functions (partials or pagelets) executed in parallel.

```
function writePartials(callback) {
  async.parallel([partial1, partial2, partial3], callback)
})
```

Note: since you've already written a response, there's not much you can do with errors except log them.

What each partial will do is send inline javascript to the client. For example, the layout can have `.stream`, and the pagelet will replace `.stream`'s `innerHTML` upon arrival, or when "the callback finishes".

```
function partialStream(callback) {
  res.render('stream.partial.ejs', function (err, html) {
    // Don't return the error in the callback
    // You may want to display an error message or something instead
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.stack)
      callback()
      return
    }

    res.write('<script>document.querySelector(".stream").innerHTML = ' + 
      JSON.stringify(html) + ';</script>')
    callback()
  })
})
```

Personally, I have `.stream.placeholder` and replace it with a new `.stream` element. The reason is I basically do `.placeholder, .placeholder ~ * {display: none}` so things don't jump around the page. However, this requires a DIY front-end framework since suddenly the JS gets more complciated.

There, your response is now streaming. Only requirement is that the client supports Javascript.

Comment: Interesting approach. I thought res.render would committ the stream, but I suppose it's not then.

Comment: it will only end the stream if it doesn't have a callback

Comment: excellent and clean solution indeed, thanks. It worked like a charm. I need now to work on the JS on the client to reorder the results as necessary, but "the proof is left as an exercise" (for me :-) )

Comment: oops. i forgot to finish the response with `</body></html>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do it just on the backend.

To minimise users' delay you need to send the minimal page to the browser and then to request the rest of the information from the browser via AJAX. Another approach to minimising delays is to send all templates to the browser on the first page load, together with the rendered page, and render all the pages in browser based on the data you request from the server. That's the way I do it. The beauty of nodejs is that you can use the same templating engine both in the backend and frontend and also share the modules.

If your page is composed in such a way that the slow information is further in HTML than the fast information, you can write response partially without using res.render (that renders complete page) and use res.write instead. I don't think though that this approach deserves serious attention as you would stuck with it sooner than you notice...

Comment: sure you can, but it's not easy: https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=389414033919

Comment: never thought about that, thanks... I need to figure out how I can get the data that is still being downloaded (in the browser I mean) as part of the same response. There are some browser events I assume...