# Executing Express res.render in a async manner

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express, pug

I have a nodejs application where `res.render` method of express is taking about 400 ms in a blocking way. How do I handle this to execute in a non blocking way? My apache benchmark takes 12 seconds for executing around 30 concurrent requests. How do I implement this in a better manner?

```
var start = +new Date;
//fetch data from redis
console.log('time taken to fetch data from redis ' + (+new Date - start)); //30 ms
res.render('some_jade_view', params);
console.log('time taken to render data ' + (+new Date - start)); //530 ms
```

I tried `process.nextTick` but it did not help much, ab results are the same.

Comment: Show us some code. Especially the part with the .render call.

Comment: @Krasimir Added code, but that is not much of help because it is the jade view that is taking 500 ms time to render. Now, I noticed it is blocking in nature. `res` is response object which is passed on to the express route.

Comment: Is the jade view extremely complex? Do you have any middleware added that could be delaying the render?

Comment: @WiredPrairie It is not that complex, it just creates about 200 KB of HTML ;) Well, still the problem is to make this `res.render` non-blocking so that even if it is complex, it would work for 30 simultaneous connections.

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280917/async-parallel-request-partial-render. There's not some switch that can make a long blocking call that needs to render sequentially asynchronous.

Comment: Or course, the best option is to make sure the payload is small as possible, and don't use Nodejs for busy work like sending lots of static HTML content to the client.

Comment: @WiredPrairie This is not static HTML content. Entirely dynamic jade views.

Comment: Is NODE_ENV set to production on the machine you're benchmarking? IIRC the templates will be cached when in production, which should speed up the rendering some.

Comment: @AndreasHultgren Yes it is set for production.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should really take a look into https://github.com/caolan/async.

Directly from Async's repo:

> Async is a utility module which provides straight-forward, powerful
>   functions for working with asynchronous JavaScript. (...)
>
> Async provides around 20 functions that include the usual 'functional'
>   suspects (map, reduce, filter, each…) as well as some common patterns
>   for asynchronous control flow (parallel, series, waterfall…). All
>   these functions assume you follow the node.js convention of providing
>   a single callback as the last argument of your async function.

Cheers.

**Edit:** I'm not sure if rendering your view in an asynchronous manner would really help you reduce your times. You may want to implement a stream on the client side that fetches and templates the data as it is coming along. You could use a front end framework like [Angular](http://angularjs.org/) for that, or do it manually.