# Executing res.render asynchronously in express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, router

I try to make this router response asynchronous:

```
var express = require('express'),
    router  = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('contact', {
    titleShown: true,
    title: 'Contact'
  });
});
```

I tried to implement `async` that I read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977996/executing-express-res-render-in-a-async-manner), but not working:

```
var express = require('express'),
    router  = express.Router(),
    async   = require('async');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  async.parallel([
    res.render('contact', {
      titleShown: true,
      title: 'Contact'
    })
  ], req);
});
```

How can I do that?

Error message that I got when I use the `--trace-sync-io` flag:

```
WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at fs.statSync (fs.js:892:18)
    at tryStat (C:\www\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:169:15)
    at resolve (C:\www\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:142:14)
    at lookup (C:\www\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:110:17)
    at View (C:\www\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:85:20)
    at render (C:\www\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:569:12)
    at render (C:\www\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:961:7)
    at C:\www\node\website\routes\contact.js:9:7
    at handle (C:\www\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: what do you mean by response asynchronously?

Comment: Line 9 column 9 in contact.js is `res.render`, that's why I thought it's not asynchronous. I updated my question with the error message.

Comment: res.render is already asyncronous.
if you do:

  `router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
     res.render('contact', {title: 'contact'}, (err, html) => {
       console.log('sent this static stuff');
     });
     console.log('this is async');
   });


you can probably see what 'this is async' string can appear before 'sent this static stuff' because all this stuff is async.`

Comment: It's express-handlebars templating engine. From the error message seems like something using `fs.statSync` which is the synchronous form of `fs.stat`. Why Express using `fs.statSync` in this case?

Comment: rename contact.js to contact.hbs !!And if u still get the error then the problem is with content of you contact

Comment: Here is the router, imagine one plus added line after `router  = express.Router();`, the error exactly at `res.[ERROR_HERE]render`: https://github.com/DJviolin/lantosistvan/blob/c67edbd80baa1998728ef2da05c6118a6beb3cad/routes/contact.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `res.render` is not fully asynchronous (at the moment). So the error is really coming from `res.render`:

> Yes, there are sync parts of the res.render API (which sucks), but it
>   will be addressed in Express 5.0, as we cannot address it without
>   breaking the view engine compatibility.
>
> Starting your application with NODE_ENV=production or setting the
>   cache to true for rendering will cause file system activities only
>   once per view at startup, which makes this a non-issue while the
>   application is fully running in production, since no sync file systems
>   are called since the views are cached.

[Source](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2960)